# Powershell bind argument path

Tags: powershell

When I execute a particular script, the Write-Log function throws an error. This appears to be before I call the function.  It is loaded from an external file.   This problem is new, it worked previously with no issues.

**Error**

There are two errors, split by a VERBOSE output statement.  The 2nd VERBOSE line is the last script line I included.  The format (not colours) is the best I can recreate

```
C:\Scripts>powershell -file tca_export_tt_ftps.ps1
Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At C:\scripts\Function-Write-Log.ps1:75 char:24
+         if ((Test-Path $Path) -AND $NoClobber) {
+                        ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

VERBOSE: Testing C:\Scripts\log\ exists
Out-File : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is an empty string.
At C:\scripts\Function-Write-Log.ps1:110 char:67
+ ... FormattedDate $LevelText $Message" | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append
+                                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

VERBOSE: Logfile is: C:\Scripts\log\kh_tca_out_20210222.log
```

**Start of my Script**

```
Function Upload-TCA
{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [Alias('StartDate')]
        [Alias('SeedDate')]
        [DateTime]$dateSeed = (Get-Date),
        #[string]$dateSeedStr = (Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"),

   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Alias('DisableFtp')] 
        [bool]$ftpDisabled=$false,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Alias('DisplayConfig')] 
        [bool]$emitConfig = $false,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$orgCode
         
    ) 

    #########################################################################
    # Function Imports
    #########################################################################

    . c:\scripts\Function-Generate-Folder.ps1

    . c:\scripts\Function-Write-Log.ps1

    . c:\scripts\Function-Upload-WinSCP-FTPS.ps1

    . c:\scripts\Function-Create-CredentialFromFile.ps1

    #########################################################################
    # Logging Setup
    #########################################################################
    $logDir = "C:\Scripts\log\"
    Generate-Folder $logDir
    $logName = "$orgCode_tca_out_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd").log"
    $logFile = Join-Path -Path $logDir -ChildPath $logName
    Write-Log "Logfile is: $logFile"  -Path $logFile
```

**Write-Log**

The Write-Log function is from the [Microsoft Script Center](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0)  Included here in case the link is broken

```
<# 
.Synopsis 
   Write-Log writes a message to a specified log file with the current time stamp. 
.DESCRIPTION 
   The Write-Log function is designed to add logging capability to other scripts. 
   In addition to writing output and/or verbose you can write to a log file for 
   later debugging. 
.NOTES 
   Created by: Jason Wasser @wasserja 
   Modified: 11/24/2015 09:30:19 AM   
 
   Changelog: 
    * Code simplification and clarification - thanks to @juneb_get_help 
    * Added documentation. 
    * Renamed LogPath parameter to Path to keep it standard - thanks to @JeffHicks 
    * Revised the Force switch to work as it should - thanks to @JeffHicks 
 
   To Do: 
    * Add error handling if trying to create a log file in a inaccessible location. 
    * Add ability to write $Message to $Verbose or $Error pipelines to eliminate 
      duplicates. 
.PARAMETER Message 
   Message is the content that you wish to add to the log file.  
.PARAMETER Path 
   The path to the log file to which you would like to write. By default the function will  
   create the path and file if it does not exist.  
.PARAMETER Level 
   Specify the criticality of the log information being written to the log (i.e. Error, Warning, Informational) 
.PARAMETER NoClobber 
   Use NoClobber if you do not wish to overwrite an existing file. 
.EXAMPLE 
   Write-Log -Message 'Log message'  
   Writes the message to c:\Logs\PowerShellLog.log. 
.EXAMPLE 
   Write-Log -Message 'Restarting Server.' -Path c:\Logs\Scriptoutput.log 
   Writes the content to the specified log file and creates the path and file specified.  
.EXAMPLE 
   Write-Log -Message 'Folder does not exist.' -Path c:\Logs\Script.log -Level Error 
   Writes the message to the specified log file as an error message, and writes the message to the error pipeline. 
.LINK 
   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0 
#> 
function Write-Log 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [Alias("LogContent")] 
        [string]$Message, 
 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [Alias('LogPath')] 
        [string]$Path='C:\Logs\PowerShellLog.log', 
         
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [ValidateSet("Error","Warn","Info")] 
        [string]$Level="Info", 
         
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [switch]$NoClobber 
    ) 
 
    Begin 
    { 
        # Set VerbosePreference to Continue so that verbose messages are displayed. 
        $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' 
    } 
    Process 
    { 
         
        # If the file already exists and NoClobber was specified, do not write to the log. 
        if ((Test-Path $Path) -AND $NoClobber) { 
            Write-Error "Log file $Path already exists, and you specified NoClobber. Either delete the file or specify a different name." 
            Return 
            } 
 
        # If attempting to write to a log file in a folder/path that doesn't exist create the file including the path. 
        elseif (!(Test-Path $Path)) { 
            Write-Verbose "Creating $Path." 
            $NewLogFile = New-Item $Path -Force -ItemType File 
            } 
 
        else { 
            # Nothing to see here yet. 
            } 
 
        # Format Date for our Log File 
        $FormattedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
 
        # Write message to error, warning, or verbose pipeline and specify $LevelText 
        switch ($Level) { 
            'Error' { 
                Write-Error $Message 
                $LevelText = 'ERROR:' 
                } 
            'Warn' { 
                Write-Warning $Message 
                $LevelText = 'WARNING:' 
                } 
            'Info' { 
                Write-Verbose $Message 
                $LevelText = 'INFO:' 
                } 
            } 
         
        # Write log entry to $Path 
        "$FormattedDate $LevelText $Message" | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append 
    } 
    End 
    { 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The `Microsoft Script Center` was decommissioned/taken offline a few months back. So, any this from there you may have no longer exists for public reference/consumtion.

Comment: Microsoft >_<    Good thing i pasted it in then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't read the Generate-Folder method correctly.  I changed the calls in there for Write-Log to Write-Host.  It was trying to use the log before it was fully setup.

```
Function Generate-Folder()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [string]$path='C:\scripts\logs'    
    )

    Write-Host "Testing $path exists"  # cant use write-log as not setup yet
    $global:foldPath=$null
    foreach($foldername in $path.split("\"))
    {
        $global:foldPath+=($foldername+"\")
        if(!(Test-Path $global:foldPath))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $global:foldPath
            Write-Host "$global:foldPath Folder Created Successfully"  #-Path $logFile
        }
    }   
}
```